# Why is Jenkins pointing to old JDK even after configuring openjdk-17.0.5 in tools?

Tags: docker, maven, jenkins, java-17

I am running **Jenkins 2.345** as a container in docker. The host OS is ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Now, I want to compile a maven project that requires **Java 17**, for that I have installed ***JDK 17 in Jenkins as a tool***. Now to verify whether the new JDK is working or not I am running the following pipeline.

Pipeline Script

```
pipeline 
{
    agent any

    tools
    {
        jdk 'openjdk-17.0.5'
        maven 'maven'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    env | grep -e PATH -e JAVA_HOME
                    which java
                    java -version
                    mvn -v
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After building the pipeline I got the following output log.

```
+ grep -e PATH -e JAVA_HOME
+ env
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/java/openjdk/lib/server:/opt/java/openjdk/lib:/opt/java/openjdk/../lib
PATH=/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-17.0.5/openjdk-17.0.5/bin:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven/bin:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-17.0.5/openjdk-17.0.5/bin:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven/bin:/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
JAVA_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-17.0.5/openjdk-17.0.5
+ which java
/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java
+ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.15+10 (build 11.0.15+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.15+10 (build 11.0.15+10, mixed mode)
+ mvn -v
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.
```

So even if **JAVA_HOME** value is updated but still Jenkins can only identify the ***java*** within ***/opt/java/openjdk/bin*** which was the default setting.

So can anyone identify what's wrong with Jenkins and why this problem is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just configure jenkins agents in docker and use any docker image containing java 17 as agent.
How to make it - please look here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymI02j-hqpU

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But I would also like to share that, I have solved this issue in another way.  I have removed my existing docker image of Jenkins and pulled a newer image -> jenkins/jenkins:jdk17 and with this one my problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

**Problem:**
I had a similar problem. I used jenkins/jenkins image on Docker with **jenkins/agent** as the Build Executor and the maven commands failed on the Build Executor because **my compiling project used JDK 17**, but **jenkins/agent used JDK 11**.

On the stage "**?!?!?!?!**" that can be seen in this image: [My Pipeline script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXLC1.png)

1. I ran the command: **sh 'mvn -version'**
2. As a result maven used JDK 11 (you can see it in this image: [jenkins/agent used JDK 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbaps.png))

**Solution:**
 Open Jenkins:

1. Manage Jenkins
2. Nodes and Clouds
3. Clouds (top left corner)
4. Docker Agent Templates
5. Docker Image
6. Change value from **jenkins/agent** to **jenkins/agent:jdk17**

Now Jenkins Build Executor jenkins/agent is going to use JDK 17 as in this image: [jenkins/agent runs JDK 17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHaGZ.png).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).